# How to deploy only changed files via atlassian/ftp-deploy:0.2.0 in Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: ftp, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am new to BitBucket pipelines, as I used Webhook for deploying my changes to FTP.

I have set reccommended atlassian/ftp-deploy:0.2.0 pipeline and it works fine, BUT I would like to set that **ONLY CHANGED** files are taken and sent to FTP.

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: FTP Deploy
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - pipe: atlassian/ftp-deploy:0.2.0
            variables:
              USER: 'myFTPusername'
              PASSWORD: 'myFTPpass'
              SERVER: 'myFTPserver'
              REMOTE_PATH: 'myFTPpath'
    - step:
        name: Deploy message
        deployment: test
        script:
          - echo "Deploying to main environment"
```

Any help how to set this up so it sends only changed files to FTP?

Expected output is **code for bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

Comment: Same problem in a same time :) Will check for answers, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`atlassian/ftp-deploy:0.3.6` delete all files, I found this image `wagnerstephan/bitbucket-git-ftp:latest` it's very useful, light and runs well and updates only changed files.

The first pipeline will run with an error, so select the `commit` then run again the pipeline with the `init` option selected.

```yaml
image: wagnerstephan/bitbucket-git-ftp:latest

pipelines:
  custom:
    init:
    - step:
        script:
          - git reset --hard
          - git ftp init -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" ftp://$FTP_HOST/
    deploy:
    - step:
        script:
          - git reset --hard
          - git ftp push -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" ftp://$FTP_HOST/--all
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: Deploy Develop
          deployment: develop
          script:
           - git reset --hard
           - git ftp push -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" ftp://$FTP_HOST/
    master:
    - step:
        name: Deploy production
        deployment: production
        script:
          - git reset --hard
          - git ftp push -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" ftp://$FTP_HOST/
```

NOTE: check the name of the environments in the Bitbucket repository.